# Centered content and lines on each side filling the remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class="text-mid">
  <span>TEXT</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.text-mid {
  display:block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding; 10px;
}
```

I want the arrangement as like in image →
[image]

**Edit**

I would prefer a solution w/o Flexbox

Comment: No one there on sundays?

Comment: Oh yes, we work on Sundays, the response time is a little bit longer though :)

Comment: Thank you so much for updating the title.

Comment: You're welcome...and I upvoted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easily done using the pseudo elements

By using both, this will also be completely transparent towards its background.

The main trick is to set `overflow: hidden` on the wrapper and a `width` on each pseudo enough to cover all possible width's

```css
.text-mid {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text-mid span {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.text-mid span::before,
.text-mid span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50vw;
  top: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.text-mid span::after {
  left: 100%;
}
.text-mid span::before {
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-mid">
  <span>TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like some one downvoted out of envy not logic.

Comment: @AdiYogi Maybe because I edited your question making Flexbox answers invalid ... so I updated your question so all answers is valid again, but added that you prefer one w/o.

Comment: I think makers of this website are very smart people just like Mark Zuckerberg. they have created competition among the experts who answer so that the site remains vibrant, competitive and each one should compete. downvoting this time is one of its side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the adjusted CSS, without using flexbox.

```css
.text-mid {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.middle {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.start {
  left: 0;
}

.finish {
  right: 0;
}

.start, .finish {
  transform: translateY(50%);
  position: absolute;  
  top: 50%;  
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 1px; 
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-mid">
  <span class="start"></span>
  <span class="middle">TEXT</span>
  <span class="finish"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: can we do this w/o flex?

Comment: All set, Adi. Flexbox is gone.

Comment: If my edit on the question caused you to down vote on my answer, I have now corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change your markup:

```css
.text-mid {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

.text-mid::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
  content: ' ';
  z-index: -1;
}

.text-mid span {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-mid">
  <span>TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: If my edit on the question caused you to down vote on my answer, I have now corrected that.

Comment: @LGSon I didn't downvote. Your answer works as well as the others do.

Answer (score 0):

I have added two new `DIV`'s for left and right lines. I also changed `class` `.text-mid`'s `display` to `flex`.

```css
.text-mid {
  display: flex;
}

span {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

#left {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#right {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  flex: 1;
  height: 1px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-mid">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <span>TEXT AREA</span>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we do this w/o flex?

Comment: If my edit on the question caused you to down vote on my answer, I have now corrected that.